# Can phonegap splash-screen display gif image?

Tags: cordova

I tried to set a splash-screen image for my phonegap app.When I set a static image such as png, everything goes well. Now I need a loading animation on my splash screen and I try to set a gif image instead of static image. However, after I do that I can not start my app any more.

Can phonegap splash-screen be set as gif image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't something Cordova/PhoneGap supports out of the box.

But if you're willing to dive in to Java/ObjC here are some possible approaches:

- You could make a [custom plugin](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.5.0/guide_hybrid_plugins_index.md.html#Plugin%20Development%20Guide) for which ever
  platform you are targeting that could do your animations for you. Examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21429346/ios-splash-screen-animation) and [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/113831/An-Advanced-Splash-Screen-for-Android-App).
- Different from the previous approach you could make a custom plugin that loads another webview with the GIF image in that.

Both of these suggestions require a custom plugin or at the very least modifying an existing one.