# iOS splash Screen Animation

Tags: ios, animation, splash-screen

In my app I want the splash screen to be animated I'm using the following code but the animation is not working.

```
UIImageView *splashScreen = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"Default.png"]];
[self.window.rootViewController.view addSubview: splashScreen];

[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

NSLog(@"begin splash");
[UIView animateWithDuration: 0.2
                      delay: 0.5
                    options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                animations: ^{splashScreen.alpha = 0.0;
                }
                completion: ^ (BOOL finished) {
                    [splashScreen removeFromSuperview];
                    NSLog(@"end splash");
                }
];
```

Comment: u want a splash screen? Y this much complex

Comment: Is your default screen so beautiful that I want to see it for longer than I need to? I doubt it. I'd rather start using the app as soon as it is ready. So would most people.

Comment: Where have you used this code in viewDidLoad of rootViewController or anywhere else

Comment: This post explains some possibilities for a more dynamic launch screen: http://blog.hawkimedia.com/2014/10/dynamic-interactive-launch-screens/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't animate the splash image, but you can wait until the app is launched and add your own view with an animation.

Answer (score 6):

you can't but use some tricks it will achieve

Open your AppDelegate.m and add the following code to your application didFinishLaunching or application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions function:

```
//1. add the image to the front of the view...
UIImageView *splashImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
[splashImage setImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"Default"]];
[self.window addSubview:splashImage];
[self.window bringSubviewToFront:splashImage];

//2. set an anchor point on the image view so it opens from the left
splashImage.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0.5);

//reset the image view frame
splashImage.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);

//3. animate the open
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                      delay:0.6
                    options:(UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut)
                 animations:^{

                     splashImage.layer.transform = CATransform3DRotate(CATransform3DIdentity, -M_PI_2, 0, 1, 0);
                 } completion:^(BOOL finished){

                     //remove that imageview from the view
                     [splashImage removeFromSuperview];
                 }];
```

[download sample app](https://github.com/jaysonlane/OpenBook)

[animated-splash-screen-default-png](http://jaysonlane.net/tech-blog/2012/03/path-2-0-style-animated-splash-screen-default-png/)