# Adding view controller as launch screen

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am working on a launch screen where I want to add a progress bar.
LaunchScreen.xib doesn't allows me to add a progress bar on the launch screen.

So is it possible to add a view controller as the launch screen for some time interval so I can add a progress bar on the launch screen of my project?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS splash Screen Animation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21429346/ios-splash-screen-animation)

Comment: This post explains some possibilities for a more dynamic launch screen: http://blog.hawkimedia.com/2014/10/dynamic-interactive-launch-screens/

Answer (score 27, accepted):

No,you can not. You can not add any logic code to it.

And also know that, at launch screen time. Your app is not launched at all. So your code about progress bar is not running.

I think the better way is using a launch screen first,then show a viewController with a progress bar as you like.

Comment: I want to add directly a view controller as launch screen is it possible?

Comment: As far as I know,Not possible

Answer (score 0):

Treat launch screen as progress indicator and do loading stuff before return "Yes" in applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOption.as return yes line executed then view controller load it's view. but don't try too much stuff before return yes like time consuming network operation.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can. I wanted to have control how long the LaunchScreen is visible when launching the app which I did in the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions in the AppDelegate.m file.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

{

```
int time = 3;
sleep(time);
printf("[%i] %s ***** sleeping %i seconds *****\n",__LINE__,__FUNCTION__, time);

return YES;
```

}

Comment: Don't sleep at launch