# .bak file is generated in my Xcode project after run script, is it safe to be ignored?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, git, shell

I just have followed the instruction in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40712171/13724660) to show my app version when showing a launch screen.

The issue is each time I build my app, the script will generate "Launch Screen.storyboard.bak". And it will generate a new one if I deleted the last generated file. The .bak file is tracked as a change in git.

My question, is the "Launch Screen.storyboard.bak" file safe to be ignored?
Or it must be committed to the git repository?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It is a good idea to ignore all files that are temporarily created by the IDE/editor.

Comment: I don't know Xcode well, but I strongly guess that this is a backup file created by the editor before storing your changes to disk. If you are cooperating with colleagues on the git project, they for sure would hate you if you also commit backup files. If you are the only one working on the project, you can think for yourself whether or not you want it.  I personally prefer having my backup files placed in a separate directory tree outside the git repo.