# PhoneGap splash screen animated gif doesn't work

Tags: android, cordova, gif, splash-screen

I am using .gif image in Phonegap or Cordova splash screen but its animation is not working. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can phonegap splash-screen display gif image?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16893521/can-phonegap-splash-screen-display-gif-image)

Comment: thanx for the quick reply @Nestoraj
but without **custom plugin** any another way to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [this page](http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap-build/configuring/icons-and-splash/#splashes), you have to save your splash screen as .png file, losing your animation.